# Broken Emoji After Installing ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: fonts, emoji

As soon as I install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` on either 18.04 or 18.10, Emoji stop working in browsers and the shell. They do show up fine in applications as Gedit, but they either aren’t displayed at all or in their black and white form in notifications and browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Epiphany).

Could that be because `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` messes something up in the fontconfig? How could I check and revert that? (Is it a bug?)

I couldn’t find anything about it online, so it might be an issue with my locale (German), but it definitely happens on multiple machines and Ubuntu derivatives such as elementary OS as well.

**Edit:** I’ve since found out that the black emoji in notifications are an issue within GNOME Shell, whereby the text-color gets overlaid on top of the emoji itself. However, the emoji not appearing in browsers still stands. I figure it’s because `ttf-ms-corefonts` changes something in the fontconfig so that the MS fonts are used on websites, but those changes also override the configuration that makes emoji work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem because the "minimal install" of ubuntu (19.04 disco) doesn't have emoji by default.

Try this:

```
# install emoji fonts package
sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji

# reload fonts cache
fc-cache -f -v
```

from [here](https://www.starryhope.com/linux/enable-emojis-ubuntu-1904/) and [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/emoji-support-missing-from-ubuntu-19-04-minimal-install/11083)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately that didn’t work for me. I have the `fonts-noto-color-emoji` package installed, but even after reloading the fonts cache I cannot see emoji in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the mscorefonts installer:

```
sudo apt remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then, clear the font cache:

```
fc-cache -f -v
```